# Should I use "you will again be given" or "you will be again given"?

Tags: grammar, word-order, adverb-position

I'm describing a situation which is similar to the situation in the previous paragraph, which of the following alternatives are more correct? In general, is there a rule for this?

"You will again be given N things." vs. "You will be again given N things."

Comment: There are a not insignificant number of hits in a Google search for "you will be again given", which surprises me. I would never use it. There are far more hits for "you will again be given". The usual place for a temporal or frequency adverb in 'will be V-ed' constructions is between 'will' and 'be' (or in clause-initial or terminal position). 'She has recently been seen in LA.' 'He will soon be here'. 'They will frequently be seen flying over the fields.'

Comment: That's great. Thank you both!